# What is the safest way to connect to an SQL database from Jupyter Notebook/Visual Studio Code and Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

I'm looking at the safest way accessing an SQL Server database in Jupyter notebook/Visual Studio code that is  local on my Windows 10 laptop and running Python code via pyodbc. I can currently access the same by providing  the below details  which is  not safe.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 
#DB connection details
cnxn_str = (
            "Driver={SQL Server};"
            "Server=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net;"
            "Database=xxxx;"
            "UID=xxxxx;" #User ID
            "PWD=xxxxx;" #Password
            "Encrypt=True;"
            "TrustServerCertificate=False;"
            "Connection Timeout=60")

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

To access a table and  have the table details as  a dataframe, I use the  below code:-

```
df1 = pd.read_sql("Select * from table_name WHERE conditions", cnxn)
```

How  can I safely make the same  connection and,  more less create the above  dataframe the same  way? A few things to note:-

1. I'm on a corporate  network that I have no access to editing environment variables. This is  possible though when I request an IT person to if that's the only option.
2. My UID and passwords are  my Azure Active Directory login email address and password.
3. Authentication method  to the SQL database  is the  Azure Active Directory.

Comment: By not safe do you mean because your username and password are exposed in the python script itself?  if so you can take those out into a parameter file, json or whatever it may be and lock that access down.  Then read in that json file and match the fields to the connection string fields.  Something like that.  Or you could get fancy and add encrypt/decrypt functionality

Comment: Using a settings or environmental file would be the way to go. Then someone else whom does have the notebook would need to just create their own settings file. You could, if you wanted, even include python code in your notebook to prompt the user for the settings and create said file for the later scripts.

Comment: You may not be able to create system environment variables, but surely you can create user environment variables.  Can you do `setx ONE TEST`?

Comment: I like  your  approaches @Larnu , JD and Tim. Are  you able to show a snippet of  the two sets of code @Larnu?

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes I'm able  to run setx ONE TEST.

Comment: OK, then if you need to, you CAN create user environment variables.